# Good Git repository viewer for Mac

Tags: git, macos, version-control

Can anyone recommend a good repository viewer for Git, similar to gitk, that works on Mac OS X Leopard? (I'm not saying gitk doesn't work)

Of course I would like a native Mac application, but as I haven't found any, what are the best options to gitk?

I know about gitview, but I'm looking forward to evaluate as many alternatives as possible.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitview

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's also [gitx](http://www.gitx.org), it's progressing well and under active development (multiple commits per day).

Comment: I have changed this as the accepted answer because, after several months the state of the art has changed and I finally settled with GitX.

Comment: GitX is very basic and supports very little functionality.

Comment: The link is broken. The working link now seems to be [http://gitx.frim.nl/] but the software looks really old now.

Answer (score 14):

[SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) is a great solution for me

Comment: Agreed, this is by far the nicest up-to-date solution.

Comment: Agreed too!! Incredible!! I'd looked for a good one since a long time ago. Until now, this is really by far the best app I've stumble upon. **And it's FREE!**

Comment: At this point it's not free. There is a 30 day trial and that's it.

Comment: It requires registration after 30 days, but that is free. SourceTree is my usual git tool of choice.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple under development.

- [GitNub](http://github.com/Caged/gitnub/tree/master)
- [Gitty](http://github.com/Machx/gitty/tree/master) (404, dead project)

I don't know if there are any that have hit 1.0.

Comment: Gitty's gone unchanged for nearly three months - I'm thinking it's a dead project now.

Answer (score 5):

Try SourceTree.  It's currently a free Mac client for Git that also supports Mercurial and SVN.

http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

It has the cleanest UI interface I've seen out of the handful that I have tried.

Comment: Also commercial: [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/)

Comment: This looks interesting.  Also the first product page I've seen with the word "clusterf**k" on the home page.

Answer (score 3):

Gitty is under development right now, basically I am working on it and it is in turn working off of BazaarX which is under heavy restructuring right now. Gitty will essentially be BazzarX with the Bazaar backend ripped out and a GIT backend put in instead and any UI tweaks made for GIT Differences from Bazaar (ie hashes instead of version#'s,etc. The good news is that as developers on BazaarX we have got our act together and have our respective assignments for what area of BazaarX to work on and BazaarX is being designed to be VCS agnostic which will make my job of integrating GIT Into it much easier. We also have a bunch more people working on BazaarX now which makes my job of working on Gitty easier.

Currently Gitty is the only native/Cocoa app for this that i am aware of. I can't say when i'll be done and hit 1.0 but I am happy with the direction I am going on in Gitty and BazaarX.

Comment: Gitty seems to be a dead project now, couldn't find it on your GitHub. Or maybe name changed?

Comment: Gitty is dead for the moment. In short I vastly overestimated how much work it would be and this was also before libgit2 really got backed by github and finally started to take off. I am working on related stuff right now, but I just cannot give gitty the attention it needs I am sorry to say.

Answer (score 3):

How about [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/)?

Comment: Looks interesting. I'm downloading it and will try it for a few days. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I've used SmartCVS and SmartSVN a lot and love the products. Haven't used SmartGit yet, but I'm sure they must have done a good job. Please do share your experience after you've played with it.

Comment: SmartGit is what I use. It's the best and most feature rich app I've seen after doing several comparisons. There are lots of things others don't handle well or handle at all like SVN integration.

Answer (score 2):

1.6 comes with Git GUI that works pretty well on my Mac.

Answer (score 2):

As horrible as it looks, the `git gui` and `gitk` commands are as good as any.

GitX looks extremely promising, and very Mac-like (things like QuickLook'ing any file in any revision). Gitnub is probably the furthest along in development, but it has no concept of branching currently, and is pretty basic (it does far less than gitk)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend on using this experimental version of GitX, by Nathan Kinsinger at http://github.com/brotherbard/gitx/commits/experimental until it gets merged into the main program.  I have been using it for some time now, and haven't had any problems.  You will have to manually clone the repository and build it in XCode.  I has a *way* better interface than GitX, as well as more features.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm cloning the repo right now!.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using git gui and gitk on leopard with the latest git from mac port. Works great for me.

Answer (score 1):

Gity: http://macendeavor.com/gity

Answer (score 1):

GitX is great; along with the command line tool, it's what I use.

If you want to make gitk look slightly less ugly (decent fonts and native Mac widgets) it can be done: http://effectif.com/git/making-gitk-look-good-on-mac

Answer (score 1):

Check http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout Sprout (formerly GitMac). http://sproutmacapp.com it focuses on making Git easy, and browsing and committing changes in your projects

http://sproutmacapp.com

Comment: Promoting your own product without disclosure is not permitted. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior (the last section).